# How to execute sql scripts via regex in calling script?

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I have a sqlplus script with some pl/sql code which calls some canned oracle 12c procedures in order to do partition maintenance - those procedures generate a series of sql files in a directory - each file is just a series of alter table drop partition statements.  The goal is to then execute those generated sql scripts.  The generated sql files all are named differently but all have a common naming pattern: SOA_SYS*.sql

From what I've researched, it does not seem feasible or desirable to try to call these sql scripts from within actual plsql code.  If that's the case, it seems I have 3 options:

- invoke the sql scripts from within the sqlplus script.  Is it possible to do that with the sqlplus scripting language and use a regex to get a reference to all files and then to iterate over them and execute each with @file.sql?  Or is sqlplus too limited in that regard?
- create a dbms_scheduler job that runs the sql files and schedule it for when the files will be guaranteed to have been generated.  Is it possible to invoke multiple sql scripts dynamically in a dbms_scheduler job?
- Create a cron job on the server that executes a shell script that iterates over the sql files in the directory and opens sqlplus to connect up to the db for each one and invokes it via @file.sql.

Are there other options?  Which is the recommended and simplest way to achieve the desired goal?  Thanks.

Comment: Is it necessary to create the scripts - is it feasible to run the commands you are putting in them dynamically instead? Failing that, can you create a master script that invokes the others, rather than needing a list or regex?

Answer (score 1):

There would be a lot of steps but it should be possible to do this in PL/SQL.  It would give you more control over how to run the run the statements, but it would be a lot of work.

The steps might go something like this:

1. Find the dynamic files.
2. Load each file into a CLOB.
3. Split the CLOB into multiple SQL statements and iterate them.
4. Classify the statements, to ensure that each one is an expected `ALTER` statement.
5. Remove statement terminators, probably `;` or `/`.  (Those terminators won't work in dynamic SQL.)
6. Run the statement with `execute immediate`.
7. Report on the status, with either an error message or a successful feedback message like "Table altered."  Maybe store the result in a log somewhere.

Step #1 can be achieved with an external table pre-processor shell script, as described in [this article](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513) for an example.  Step #2 might be fairly easy, simply call [DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.READ2CLOB](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_xslpro.htm#ARPLS70162).

Steps #3 to #7 can be insanely complicated depending on the complexity of the SQL statements.  Unless the SQL statements are incredibly uniform a regular expression will not be powerful enough to deal with it.  But my open source project [plsql_lexer](https://github.com/jonheller1/plsql_lexer) can handle those steps for complex SQL statements.  Even with the parsing taken care of, you're still looking at roughly 100 lines of code to deal with the results.  See the project Readme for a realistic example.

---

But it would be *much* easier to take control of the canned procedures, and make them run the statements instead of writing them to a file.  Or at least store them in a table.  I assume this is some 3rd party tool?  If so, there's probably some way to hack it to work better.

If you're lucky it's a PL/SQL program you can modify.  Did they wrap it?  Don't worry, there are plenty of un-wrappers online.

If it's running PL/SQL, but you don't have access to it, you may still be able to control it.  For example, maybe it uses `UTL_FILE` to write to the files.  But I bet they didn't fully qualify it with `SYS.UTL_FILE`.  In that case you can create your own version of `UTL_FILE` that writes data into a table instead of the file system.  Then install the package on the application schema and it will use the new package instead.